# Google Webmaster Tools and 500 Errors

Tags: google-search-console, http-code-500

I'm having issues with Google Webmasters not being able reach my pages, although they are there.  I'm getting 500 errors in Webmasters, but Google Analytics is picking up the pages ok, so I'm a bit confused!

The site is http://www.readingorders.com/ and is hosted on Appharbor.

Any help gratefully received!

Comment: Maybe there was a problem with your site at the time the Googlebot crawled?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I've been trying to solve it for days.  Even Fetch As Google is coming page with 'Unreachable Page'.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question has been closed.  I would have thought this would have helped anyone in a similar situation.

Comment: There would seem to be _something_ on your server that is blocking access to _certain_ clients. Attempting to validate your homepage using the [W3C HTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) also returns a "500 Internal Server Error". Do you have anything blocking in your .htaccess file? Or some kind of additional security module enabled on the server?

Comment: Not that I know of, but I've put in a support ticket with Appharbor and I'll post if I find a resolution.  Thanks for taking the time to look into this w3d!

Comment: Hi - sorry meant to come back and let you know the resolution.  It was two-fold 1) I hadn't made www.readingorders.com canonical with my hosting company and 2) I had some flakey code in that checked for the visitors country of origin.  Search engine robots don't hold this info as they essentially country agnostic, so some simple code to ensure that a default value was set seemed to do the trick.  I hope this helps others who get confused with 500 errors being returned by search engine robots.